# What does it mean to read from standard input and output to standard output?

Tags: c++

I'm entering a programming competition, but they say:

> Your program should not prompt for input from the user. It should read
> from the standard input and output to the standard output, e.g.:

```
$ echo 'AB' | q4
$ 3
$ q4 < input.txt
$ 3
$ cat input.txt
$ AB
```

What does this mean? Do I just use `cin` and then `cout`?

(For reference, this is the [AIPO](http://aipo.computing.dcu.ie/2015-aipo-preliminary-round-problems) website.)

Comment: well, using cin/cout would be utterly pointless if your programming language of choice is ENIAC patch cords...

Comment: Yep I know that is why I'm using c++ because they don't allow c#

Comment: Receive input from the keyboard and send output to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are redirecting standard input (which is read via `cin` in C++). That is, instead the `q4` program getting its input from a user via the keyboard, it is getting its input from somewhere else.

```
$ echo 'AB' | q4
```

That is sending the output of the echo program/command to the standard input of the `q4` program.

```
$ q4 < input.txt
```

And that is sending the contents of the file `input.txt` as the standard input.

So, yes. You just use `cin` (which handles standard input) and `cout` (which handles standard output), and when your program is invoked via the above commands, `cin` will get its input not from the keyboard, but from either a file or another program.

See the Wikipedia entry for [Redirection (computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).